# Ubuntu 19.04 lacks Switch User option in Non-Admin account

Tags: users, switch-user

The introductory procedure is:

- Click on down pointer in the upper right hand corner
- Click on user-id

For a Standard Account the options are:

- Log Out
- Account Settings

The Switch User option is missing. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> does perform a switch user action.

For an Administrator Account the options are:

- Switch User
- Log Out
- Account Settings

Here, the Switch User option is present.

Comment: I have the same for standard account on Ubuntu 18.04. I think it is not a bug. It is just the usual..